# iOS OpenGL ES 2.0 Multi-Texture Decal Images Do Not Show Up

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I am trying to use a satellite image and the base image and another image that just has a number to be a 'decal' image which I render on top of the satellite. Here are the 2 images:

[image]

[image]

My drawInRect, where I draw the earth, looks like this:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    // Clear the buffer and prepare to draw
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Enable the Earth texture
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = _earthInfo.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.target = _earthInfo.target;

    // Bind the earth vertex array
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_earthVertexArray);

    // Render the object with GLKit
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    // Draw elements from the index array and uv / vertex / normal info
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,Earth_polygoncount*3,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

    // Turn on Blending before displaying satellites
    // so that the satellite image ( which has alpha )
    // shows up OK
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    // Now billboard something
    [self createBillboardAtLat:35 andLon:-97];

    // Now billboard something
    [self createBillboardAtLat:0 andLon:0];

    // Now billboard something
    [self createBillboardAtLat:-65 andLon:-137];

}
```

I attempt to draw my images using GLKBaseEffect's texture2d0 and texture2d1 ( GLKTextureEnvModeDecal ) in the 'createBillboardAtLat' method like this:

```
// Get the current modelview matrix
GLKMatrix4 originalMat = self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix;
GLKMatrix4 currMat = self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix;

// Print the original matrix for comparison
//NSLog(@"Original Matrix:");
//[self printMatrix:currMat];

// Define the buffer designators
GLuint billboardVertexArray;
GLuint billboardVertexBuffer;
GLuint billboardIndexBuffer;

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &billboardVertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(billboardVertexArray);

// Now draw the billboard
glGenBuffers(1, &billboardVertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, billboardVertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Billboard_vertex), Billboard_vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &billboardIndexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, billboardIndexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Billboard_index), Billboard_index, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// u0,v0,normalx0,normaly0,normalz0,x0,y0,z0
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(float), BUFFER_OFFSET(5));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(float), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(float), BUFFER_OFFSET(2));

// Enable the Satellite texture
self.effect.texture2d0.name = _billBoardTextureInfo.name;
self.effect.texture2d0.target = _billBoardTextureInfo.target;
self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;

// Set up the decal number texture
self.effect.texture2d1.name = _billBoardDecalTextureInfo.name;
self.effect.texture2d1.enabled = YES;
self.effect.texture2d1.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeDecal;

// Bind the earth vertex array
glBindVertexArrayOES(billboardVertexArray);
```

However, my number never shows up! Here is my result after building:

[image]

How do I get my two images to be blended together??

```
// Enable the Satellite texture
self.effect.texture2d0.name = _billBoardTextureInfo.name;
self.effect.texture2d0.target = _billBoardTextureInfo.target;
self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;

// Set up the decal number texture
self.effect.texture2d1.name = _billBoardDecalTextureInfo.name;
self.effect.texture2d1.enabled = YES;
self.effect.texture2d1.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeDecal;
```

UPDATE!

So if I set my blendfunc to this:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Then I get the decals showing up but the numbers are only about 80% opaque - I can still see some of the earth underneath when I move them and also when they rotate so that there is no earth behind but just white from the background, they disappear! What could cause this?

Comment: I see where you're setting up the earth image and the satellite image. Where are you setting up the image with the number in it?

Comment: He is using multitexturing when drawing the satellites.

Comment: Yea sorry my comments were wrong - I've fixed them now. _billboardTextureInfo is the satellite and _billboardDecalTextureInfo is the number.